# After Feature Layer reference is added all dojo references are not recognized

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I'm creating a simple javascript management system in which I have to query 6 feature layer services, edit, add or delete data from the services. Every time I want to add the Feature Layer reference all other functions stop working. It is like dojo and arcgis.js are not being loaded anymore. 
Here is an example of the code I wrote:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dijit/form/ComboBox", 
    "dojo/parser", "esri/tasks/query",
    "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "esri/tasks/GeometryService", 
 "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "dojo/domReady!"],

function (dom, on, ComboBox, parser, Query, QueryTask, GeometryService, FeatureLayer) {
    parser.parse();
    var link = '';
    var linkEN = "";
    var linkALB = ""; 
    esri.config.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("https://utility.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
    dijit.byId("id_category").on("change", function () {
        var category = dijit.byId("id_category").value;
        alert(category);
});
        function categorySelected(link) {
        var queryTask = new QueryTask(link);
        console.log("link " + link);
        var query = new Query();
        query.where = '1=1';
        query.returnGeometry = false;
        query.outFields = ["*"];
        queryTask.execute(query, populateList);
        on(dom.byId("id_category"), "change", execute);
    };
    function execute() {
        queryTask.execute(query, populateList);
    }
              .
             here goes the code for populating the list and displaying data 
               ..

            dijit.byId("btn_save").on("click", function () {
        alert("start editing ");

        // create feature layer 
        var pointsOfInterest = new FeatureLayer("link", {
           mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            outFields: ['*']
        });
        console.log(pointsOfInterest);
    });
```

All this code is working fine until the Feature Layer reference is added. After that none of the functionalities work, not even the alert from selected category. 
I'm using the latest version of arcgis javascript api - 3.16